# How to select a single ID among many returned by Amazon API?

Tags: php, xml

I am working with the Amazon API, and they send be the response in XML format. I am trying to sort through the data, but since there are 15 different tags that I am looking for, I am not exactly sure how to go about this. I know that there is `dom->getElementByTagName('')`. I am wondering how I would go about finding all 15 results. The response is as follows:

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="082686322638" IdType="UPC" status="Success">
        <ns2:ListPrice>
          <ns2:Amount>9.99</ns2:Amount>
          <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
        </ns2:ListPrice>
    <SalesRankings>
      <SalesRank>
 <ProductCategoryId>toy_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>4150</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>2229575011</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>8</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
    </SalesRankings>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

This is repeated 3 times.

I am looking for:

The Id value in `<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="082686322638" IdType="UPC" status="Success">`

`<ns2:Amount></ns2:Amount>`

```
  <SalesRank>
 <ProductCategoryId>toy_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>4150</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
```

How do I add all 3 tags to my code?

So far, I have this:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $items) { 
echo $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult['Id'] . ','; 
echo $items->Product->SalesRankings->SalesRank->Rank . ", "; 
echo $items->Products->Product->ns2:Amount . ", "; }
```

Comment: On the one hand you say, *I am looking for: The Id value*, but on the other hand you ask,  *How do I add all 3 tags [what tags???] to my code?*   **Your question is unclear; your code fragment, incomplete.**  I've [shown you how to use XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34503406/290085) to get the `Id` attribute of one of the `GetMatchingProductForIdResult` elements, but beyond that, I can't guess what else you might be trying to ask.

Comment: Voting to close: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you specifically want the `Id` of the `GetMatchingProductForIdResult` with `IdType` equal to "UPC",

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$id = $xpath->query("//GetMatchingProductForIdResult[@IdType='UPC']/@Id");
```

then `$id` will be `082686322638` as requested.

Comment: Please don't add code in comments.   Use the [edit] link and update your question.   Thanks.